# NGINX: Redirect a user based on cookie for a specific URL only

Tags: redirect, cookies, nginx, server

I'm building a closed social network and currently when a user is not logged in they will always be redirected to the homepage of my domain.

What I would like to do is do the following:

1. Use NGINX to check if a user is logged in (through checking for a cookie) and then when they go to the homepage (mydomain.com) redirect to to mydomain.com/newsfeed.
2. This check should only be applied when a user brows to the homepage and should not work at ANY other url (or else they would always be redirected).

I'm very new to NGINX and looked at various tutorials for using cookies for redirect but failed to get an answer (most notably to limiting the redirect to only the homepage).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But why do you want to use nginx? It's totally and easily doable on WordPress.

Comment: I have it working with WP redirect. But that still needs to load a big chunk of PHP and I noticed it's pretty darn slow to redirect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Final correct solution:

```
location ~* ^/$ {
 if ($http_cookie ~* "wordpress_logged_in") {
    return 301 http://example.com/newsfeed/;
 }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use 301 since its a permanent redirect, and the redirect you want is only for when logged in. rather use 302.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ Don't use if in a location context

Comment: @MatthewHaworth don't just scream you can't use `if` inside the location context. The (only) 100% safe things which may be done inside `if` in a location context are: `return ...;` and `rewrite ... last;`. The above example uses `return` which is totally fine.

Comment: Exact match `location = / { ... }` will be faster than regex `location ~ ^/$ { ... }`

Comment: Keep in mind that there is also the [`$cookie_*name*` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_cookie_) (looking at the use of `$http_cookie` in the answer).

Answer (score 6):

Let's pretend I've a cookie like so: `name=value`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location ~* ^/$ {
        if ($cookie_name = "value") {
            return 301 http://example.com/newsfeed/;
        }
    }
}
```

The location block will only match the homepage, check that the cookie exists (you could also just use `if ($cookie_name)`), and if present, redirect the user to `http://example.com/newsfeed/`