# Redirect to dashboard from home page based on user cookie

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, nginx, web

What I am trying to accomplish should be straight forward but since I have no experience in web development I would be more than happy to get some insights on best practices to accomplish user redirection from home page to dashboard if user is logged in.

- Home page is a static WordPress site which is run in a docker container.
- Dashboard is a single page application developed with AngularJS.
- Nginx is used as a reverse proxy.

Authentication is basically a JWT. When user loggs in JWT is stored in `Cookie`.

If cookie is set user should be redirected to dashboard. Otherwise home page should be returned.

Should I configure Nginx to check for a cookie when accessing `domain.com/` and redirect to `app.domain.com` if cookie exists?

Comment: look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278910/nginx-redirect-a-user-based-on-cookie-for-a-specific-url-only

Comment: My concern is how it affects browser caching. Should cache be disabled to always force checking existence of a Cookie?

Comment: you're refering to offline content. the browser will send request to the web server anyway, and the browser check in the headers about content changes.

Answer (score 0):

what you are describing is a scenario where you need to go to home page and check whether User is Authenticated there, and redirect -before showing the homepage- if the user is authenticated from within the homepage code.

Comment: Homepage should be a standalone WordPress site with no concern about user Authentication. It shouldn't be modified in any way. That is the concern.