# Checking Nginx cookie's data does not work as expected

Tags: nginx, cookies, reverse-proxy

Although I have been reading and testing many things I could not get a working solution. I want to do something simple, I want to restrict access to some folders to only logged users. If an user is not logged it should get a redirect to the login page.

I do not want to serve files directly using another script. I want to serve files only to authenticated files, I know that it is possible because I saw some websites like Dropbox (not sure if they use nginx) and other services (with nginx in the headers) do not allow direct access to public files without being logged.

1. I guess that once the user is authenticated I should add a cookie in the header in the backed so I should be able to check it in Nginx. But I do not know if I can set the cookie and do the check entirely in Nginx
2. I need to whitelist login and register urls. Because if I check if one cookie exists in the request and it does not exist, I will enter into an infinite loop in the login/register urls
3. If the cookie does not exist or is not valid, it should redirect user to the login page

I checked the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278910/nginx-redirect-a-user-based-on-cookie-for-a-specific-url-only) which is almost the same as mine:

And I have been trying the next config:

```
location ~* ^/assets/users/images/(.*)$ {
 if ($cookie_cookieafterlogin != "secret_value") {
    return 301 https://example_domain.com/login;
 }
}
```

I must say that I am a newbie to Nginx and I am starting to learn now. So the above code is partially working because it blocks direct access to anymous access but it also blocks access for logged users, so I think that I am not setting properly the cookie in my web app.

Once the user is authenticated I am sending in the header my cookie data and checking headers in the browser I can see this:

```
Set-Cookie cookieafterlogin=secret_value; expires=Sun, 13-Jun-2021 ....
```

Anyone could say me where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Set-Cookie` is a HTTP response header used to ask user browser to store some cookie locally. You should rather check `Cookie` HTTP request header to see if correct cookie value is passed from browser to server. However I don't see any errors in your config besides you can use a quickly faster `location /assets/users/images/ { ... }` (so called _prefix_ location) rather than _regex matching_ location ([see](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) the docs).

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks for the advice about removing regex from location block, you are right! Also if the rest is fine I think that I identified where is the issue. I am setting new cookie in Symfony and because the image directory is in the public directory those routes are handled directly through Nginx (and my cookie is not there). Should I create a new cookie based in a cookie from my webapp? (Sorry if it is not a good explanation)